# Magnetic Field Strength $B$ of a Wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I understand that magnetic field strength $B$ decreases by 2 pi r assuming I and permeability is constant.

Is r assumed to be from the edge of the wire or the centre of the wire?

If it is from the centre of the wire is the change in $B$ the same over the radius as it is from the edge to some point away from the wire? Or should a new value for permeability be chosen?

Answer (score 1):

The expression for the magnetic field comes from [Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law). This tells us that for a circular field line around the wire the field times the circumference of the circle has to be equal to $\mu_0$ times the total current enclosed by the circle.

So the $r$ in the expression for the field:

$$ B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r} \tag{1}$$

comes from the fact the circumference of the circle is $2\pi r$ i.e. $r$ is the distance from the centre of the circle.

So the simple answer is that $r$ is measured from the centre of the wire, but this simple answer is a little misleading. It is measured from the centre of the wire only because the wire is at the centre of the circle. Equation (1) is true for any current distribution inside the circle as long as that distribution is axially symmetric. For example if we had current flowing in a cylinder instead of a wire the equation would still apply where now $r$ is measured to the axis of the cylinder.

If the distance $r$ is inside the wire there are two factors that change. The permeability does indeed change, but for non-ferromagnets the permeability doesn't change much. More important is that inside the wire the circle only encloses part of the current i.e. only some of the current flowing through the wire is inside the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Ampere's law for magnetic field is equivalent of Gauss law for electric field, they define circulation or flow of field in a region depends upon amount of source contained in it. Thus curl of magnetic field and magnetic field is given by,
$$\oint B\,dl=\mu I=\iint\nabla\times B\,dS=\iint\mu J\,dS$$
$$B=\dfrac{\mu I}{2\pi r}$$
Now if radius of solid cylindrical conductor is $R$ in which current is flowing uniformly along axial direction then magnetic field at a distance $r$ from the centre of axis is given by,
$$B=\dfrac{\mu I}{2\pi r}\,,\quad\text{for}\,\, r\ge R\\B=\dfrac{\mu I'}{2\pi r}=\dfrac{\mu I}{2\pi R^2}r\,,\quad \text{for}\,\, r\le R$$
where $I'= I\left(\dfrac{r}{R}\right)^2$, because from Ampere's law,
$$\nabla\times B=0\,,\quad\text{for}\quad r\ge R\\ \nabla\times B=\mu J\,,\quad\text{for}\quad r\lt R$$

So outside the cylinder, new value of permeability is required if there is change in value from conductor. Unlike electric field, magnetic field is increasing linearly from centre of conductor to surface of the conductor. Reason is that magnetic field is discontinuous in tangential direction while strength is dependent on radial direction.